# Installation of Couchbase Python SDK 3.0.10 failing on python 3.8.5

Tags: python, couchbase

I am unable to install Couchbase Python SDK of version 3.0.10 (I specifically need this version). I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and with pyenv set global python to 3.8.5. I am also using poetry with venv. (Installation fails both in venv and globally). It seems that I tried out everything - using different python versions (3.8, 3.9, 3.10), having all requirements set up, installing docutils. At this point I don't know what else is there to try.

The requirements mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.couchbase.com/python-sdk/3.0/project-docs/sdk-release-notes.html) are installed.:

```
sudo apt install git-all python3-dev python3-pip python3-setuptools cmake build-essential libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Here is the error that I am receiving:

```
$ python3 -m pip install couchbase==3.0.10
Collecting couchbase==3.0.10
  Using cached couchbase-3.0.10.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=19.1.0 in ./.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from couchbase==3.0.10) (21.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt>=1.11.2 in ./.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from couchbase==3.0.10) (1.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent>=0.15.2 in ./.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from couchbase==3.0.10) (0.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: mypy-extensions in ./.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from couchbase==3.0.10) (0.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from couchbase==3.0.10) (1.16.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: couchbase
  Building wheel for couchbase (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for couchbase (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [900 lines of output]
      /tmp/pip-install-jdv9fnu7/couchbase_3a9b26b317cc4b378fb5eef06c0a77be/gen_config.py:55: UserWarning: problem: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/tmp/pip-install-jdv9fnu7/couchbase_3a9b26b317cc4b378fb5eef06c0a77be/gen_config.py", line 36, in get_lcb_min_version
          import docutils.parsers.rst
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docutils'
      
        warnings.warn("problem: {}".format(traceback.format_exc()))
      ERROR:root:{'ext_modules': [<cmake_build.CMakeExtension('couchbase_core._libcouchbase') at 0x7f823cb3ae20>]}
      INFO:root:running bdist_wheel
      INFO:root:running build
      INFO:root:running build_py
      INFO:root:creating build
      INFO:root:creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38
      INFO:root:creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/txcouchbase
      INFO:root:copying txcouchbase/cluster.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/txcouchbase
      INFO:root:copying txcouchbase/iops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/txcouchbase
      INFO:root:copying txcouchbase/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/txcouchbase
      INFO:root:creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core/iops
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/iops/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core/iops
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/iops/select.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core/iops
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/iops/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core/iops
      INFO:root:creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/bucket.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/cluster.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/auth.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/options.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/JSONdocument.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/n1ql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/diagnostics.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/analytics.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/durability.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/search.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/result.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/collection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/subdocument.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/mutation_state.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase
      INFO:root:creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core/asynchronous
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/asynchronous/view.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core/asynchronous
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/asynchronous/n1ql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core/asynchronous
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/asynchronous/client.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core/asynchronous
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/asynchronous/analytics.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core/asynchronous
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/asynchronous/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core/asynchronous
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/asynchronous/rowsbase.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core/asynchronous
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/asynchronous/events.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core/asynchronous
      INFO:root:creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/acouchbase
      INFO:root:copying acouchbase/cluster.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/acouchbase
      INFO:root:copying acouchbase/iterator.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/acouchbase
      INFO:root:copying acouchbase/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/acouchbase
      INFO:root:copying acouchbase/asyncio_iops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/acouchbase
      INFO:root:creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase/management
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/management/users.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase/management
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/management/queries.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase/management
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/management/collections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase/management
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/management/analytics.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase/management
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/management/admin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase/management
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/management/buckets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase/management
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/management/search.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase/management
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/management/views.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase/management
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/management/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase/management
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/management/generic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase/management
      INFO:root:creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase/asynchronous
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/asynchronous/search.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase/asynchronous
      INFO:root:copying couchbase/asynchronous/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase/asynchronous
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/analytics_ingester.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/mockserver.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/transcoder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/cluster.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/supportability.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/_logutil.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/n1ql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/_bootstrap.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/_pyport.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/client.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/connstr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/analytics.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/durability.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/bucketmanager.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/transcodable.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/crypto.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/priv_constants.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/experimental.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/result.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/_ixmgmt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/mapper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/user_constants.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/items.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/subdocument.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core
      INFO:root:creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core/views
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/views/iterator.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core/views
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/views/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core/views
      INFO:root:copying couchbase_core/views/params.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core/views
      INFO:root:running build_ext
      Build type: CMAKE_HYBRID, cmake:True
      []
      {}
      set base as None
      Got platform linux
      got pkgs ['libcouchbase.so.6']
      Got platform linux
      yielding binary libcouchbase.so.6 : /tmp/pip-install-jdv9fnu7/couchbase_3a9b26b317cc4b378fb5eef06c0a77be/couchbase_core/libcouchbase.so.6
      From: temp_build_dir build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38 and ssl_relative_path None Got ssl_abs_path /tmp/pip-install-jdv9fnu7/couchbase_3a9b26b317cc4b378fb5eef06c0a77be/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/openssl
```

This is not a full error log, I cut the middle part since there seemed like no useful error messages, here is the ending:

```
INFO:root:creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src
      INFO:root:gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -I/home/my-pc/PycharmProjects/my-project/.venv/include -I/home/my-pc/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -c src/bucket.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/bucket.o -Wno-strict-prototypes -fPIC -std=c11 -Wuninitialized -Wswitch -Werror -Wno-missing-braces -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04 -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04
      INFO:root:gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -I/home/my-pc/PycharmProjects/my-project/.venv/include -I/home/my-pc/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -c src/callbacks.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/callbacks.o -Wno-strict-prototypes -fPIC -std=c11 -Wuninitialized -Wswitch -Werror -Wno-missing-braces -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04 -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04
      INFO:root:gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -I/home/my-pc/PycharmProjects/my-project/.venv/include -I/home/my-pc/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -c src/cntl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/cntl.o -Wno-strict-prototypes -fPIC -std=c11 -Wuninitialized -Wswitch -Werror -Wno-missing-braces -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04 -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04
      INFO:root:gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -I/home/my-pc/PycharmProjects/my-project/.venv/include -I/home/my-pc/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -c src/connevents.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/connevents.o -Wno-strict-prototypes -fPIC -std=c11 -Wuninitialized -Wswitch -Werror -Wno-missing-braces -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04 -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04
      INFO:root:gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -I/home/my-pc/PycharmProjects/my-project/.venv/include -I/home/my-pc/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -c src/constants.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/constants.o -Wno-strict-prototypes -fPIC -std=c11 -Wuninitialized -Wswitch -Werror -Wno-missing-braces -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04 -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04
      INFO:root:gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -I/home/my-pc/PycharmProjects/my-project/.venv/include -I/home/my-pc/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -c src/convert.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/convert.o -Wno-strict-prototypes -fPIC -std=c11 -Wuninitialized -Wswitch -Werror -Wno-missing-braces -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04 -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04
      INFO:root:gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -I/home/my-pc/PycharmProjects/my-project/.venv/include -I/home/my-pc/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -c src/counter.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/counter.o -Wno-strict-prototypes -fPIC -std=c11 -Wuninitialized -Wswitch -Werror -Wno-missing-braces -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04 -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04
      INFO:root:gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -I/home/my-pc/PycharmProjects/my-project/.venv/include -I/home/my-pc/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -c src/crypto.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/crypto.o -Wno-strict-prototypes -fPIC -std=c11 -Wuninitialized -Wswitch -Werror -Wno-missing-braces -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04 -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04
      INFO:root:gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -I/home/my-pc/PycharmProjects/my-project/.venv/include -I/home/my-pc/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -c src/ctranscoder.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/ctranscoder.o -Wno-strict-prototypes -fPIC -std=c11 -Wuninitialized -Wswitch -Werror -Wno-missing-braces -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04 -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04
      INFO:root:gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -I/home/my-pc/PycharmProjects/my-project/.venv/include -I/home/my-pc/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -c src/exceptions.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/exceptions.o -Wno-strict-prototypes -fPIC -std=c11 -Wuninitialized -Wswitch -Werror -Wno-missing-braces -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04 -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04
      INFO:root:gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -I/home/my-pc/PycharmProjects/my-project/.venv/include -I/home/my-pc/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -c src/ext.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/ext.o -Wno-strict-prototypes -fPIC -std=c11 -Wuninitialized -Wswitch -Werror -Wno-missing-braces -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04 -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04
      INFO:root:gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -I/home/my-pc/PycharmProjects/my-project/.venv/include -I/home/my-pc/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -c src/fts.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/fts.o -Wno-strict-prototypes -fPIC -std=c11 -Wuninitialized -Wswitch -Werror -Wno-missing-braces -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04 -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04
      INFO:root:gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -I/home/my-pc/PycharmProjects/my-project/.venv/include -I/home/my-pc/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -c src/get.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/get.o -Wno-strict-prototypes -fPIC -std=c11 -Wuninitialized -Wswitch -Werror -Wno-missing-braces -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04 -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04
      INFO:root:gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -I/home/my-pc/PycharmProjects/my-project/.venv/include -I/home/my-pc/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -c src/htresult.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/htresult.o -Wno-strict-prototypes -fPIC -std=c11 -Wuninitialized -Wswitch -Werror -Wno-missing-braces -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04 -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04
      INFO:root:gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -I/home/my-pc/PycharmProjects/my-project/.venv/include -I/home/my-pc/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/include -c src/iops.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/iops.o -Wno-strict-prototypes -fPIC -std=c11 -Wuninitialized -Wswitch -Werror -Wno-missing-braces -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04 -DPYCBC_LCB_API=0x02FF04
      src/iops.c: In function ‘update_event’:
      src/iops.c:412:17: error: array subscript ‘lcb_uint32_t {aka unsigned int}[0]’ is partly outside array bounds of ‘short int[1]’ [-Werror=array-bounds]
        412 |         usecs = *(lcb_uint32_t*)arg;
            |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      src/iops.c:516:69: note: while referencing ‘flags’
        516 | update_event(lcb_io_opt_t io, lcb_socket_t sock, void *event, short flags,
            |                                                               ~~~~~~^~~~~
      src/iops.c: In function ‘delete_event’:
      src/iops.c:412:17: error: array subscript ‘lcb_uint32_t {aka unsigned int}[0]’ is partly outside array bounds of ‘short int[1]’ [-Werror=array-bounds]
        412 |         usecs = *(lcb_uint32_t*)arg;
            |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      src/iops.c:548:11: note: while referencing ‘tmp’
        548 |     short tmp = 0;
            |           ^~~
      cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
      
      Got platform linux
      self.base is ['build', 'temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38']
      self.base is ['build', 'temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38']
      self.base is ['build', 'temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38']
      self.base is ['build', 'temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38']
      copying build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/lib/Release/libcouchbase.so.6 to /tmp/pip-install-jdv9fnu7/couchbase_3a9b26b317cc4b378fb5eef06c0a77be/build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/couchbase_core/libcouchbase.so.6
      success
      self.base is ['build', 'temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38']
      self.base is ['build', 'temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38']
      self.base is ['build', 'temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38']
      self.base is ['build', 'temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38']
      copying build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/install/lib/Release/libcouchbase.so.6 to /tmp/pip-install-jdv9fnu7/couchbase_3a9b26b317cc4b378fb5eef06c0a77be/couchbase_core/libcouchbase.so.6
      success
      self.base is ['build', 'temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38']
      self.base is ['build', 'temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38']
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for couchbase
Failed to build couchbase
ERROR: Could not build wheels for couchbase, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

The error at the beginning mentioning ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docutils' has been tried out. I have this installed both in venv and globally:

```
$ pip3 install docutils                                                         
Requirement already satisfied: docutils in ./.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.19)
```

Installing with poetry install returns the same result, although some pip paths for example has changed (or represented differently) which seems to have something to do with different python version (3.10)

Here is the error from using poetry install:

```
 Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 6 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing couchbase (3.0.10): Failed

  CalledProcessError

  Command '['/home/my-pc/PycharmProjects/my-project/.venv/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--use-pep517', '--disable-pip-version-check', '--isolated', '--no-input', '--prefix', '/home/my-pc/PycharmProjects/my-project/.venv', '--no-deps', '/home/my-pc/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/ee/68/10/ea670bac6fb66b1486d57a260265313756a45ab7bdee068a46fe64db38/couchbase-3.0.10.tar.gz']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

  at ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py:524 in run
       520│             # We don't call process.wait() as .__exit__ does that for us.
       521│             raise
       522│         retcode = process.poll()
       523│         if check and retcode:
    →  524│             raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
       525│                                      output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
       526│     return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode, stdout, stderr)
       527│ 
       528│ 

The following error occurred when trying to handle this error:


  EnvCommandError

  Command ['/home/my-pc/PycharmProjects/my-project/.venv/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--use-pep517', '--disable-pip-version-check', '--isolated', '--no-input', '--prefix', '/home/my-pc/PycharmProjects/my-project/.venv', '--no-deps', '/home/my-pc/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/ee/68/10/ea670bac6fb66b1486d57a260265313756a45ab7bdee068a46fe64db38/couchbase-3.0.10.tar.gz'] errored with the following return code 1, and output: 
  Processing /home/my-pc/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/ee/68/10/ea670bac6fb66b1486d57a260265313756a45ab7bdee068a46fe64db38/couchbase-3.0.10.tar.gz
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Installing backend dependencies: started
    Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
  Building wheels for collected packages: couchbase
    Building wheel for couchbase (pyproject.toml): started
    Building wheel for couchbase (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    
    × Building wheel for couchbase (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> [834 lines of output]
        /tmp/pip-req-build-lmxka0wp/gen_config.py:55: UserWarning: problem: Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/tmp/pip-req-build-lmxka0wp/gen_config.py", line 36, in get_lcb_min_version
            import docutils.parsers.rst
        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docutils'
```

Apologies if the question looks messy, but there are a lot of logs.
Perhaps someone has encountered a similar issue and knows how to solve it?
All help is appreciated

Comment: When you say you need version 3.0.10, you mean the Couchbase Python SDK, and not Couchbase Server 3.0.10 (which would be a very, very old outdated version of Couchbase), correct?

Comment: Yes, Couchbase Python SDK, I will update my question